# Matlab - Identifying objects in one image that overlap objects in another

Tags: image, matlab, object, image-processing

I have two images, one of some cells and another of the nuclei of those cells. I've segmented these images to give two binary images/matrices. I would like to remove cell outlines that contain no nuclei, and cells and nuclei that correspond to clusters of cells (i.e. cell outlines that contain more than one nuclei).

I really can't figure this out... I can use bwlabel to make labelled arrays of the objects:

```
[cell, cellnum] = bwlabel(cells,8);
[nuc, nucnum] = bwlabel(nuclei,8);
```

How can I compare these two arrays to get one new array that only contains cells with exactly one nucleus and another with the nuclei corresponding to these cells?

Comment: Share relevant image(s) and explain with respect to those? For sharing images, you can upload to some public image sharing website and link it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you could do is loop through the clusters you identified in your `cells` binary image (conceptual, untested code):

```
for k=1:cellnum
    [~, nucnum(k)]=bwlabel(nuclei.*(cell==k));
end
```

`nucnum` is then a vector with the number of nuclei found inside every cell. Filter according to your needs.

I recommend this blog post on the subject of segmenting cells and nuclei: http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2006/06/02/cell-segmentation/

Comment: Ok, that looks like it might be the ticket. what's happening here? We multiply the `nuclei` image array by individual `cell` subregions, and put that into the 'nucnum' array? ...and does the tilde mean we're skipping the actual region labelling?

Comment: It certainly does, thanks for the help. I hadn't realised I could take operations on images as arguments for functions like bwlabel - that makes my code a lot tidier!

Comment: Hi, can I ask one more question about this? Why is `nucnum` referencing `k` there?

Comment: @Olly with this syntax, `nuncum` is a vector that gets an additional element each time the loop is executed (at the kth position). If you run the loop without it, it will overwrite the value of `nuncum` at each execution and you will be left with only the last value.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to perform pca on the clusters afterwards, but not really getting anywhere:
    for k=1:cellnum  
    [l, nucnum]=bwlabel(nuclei.*(cell==k));  
    if nucnum == 1  
      [coeff, score] = princomp(l);  
  end  
end   
  
but this is not really working as I'd expected... turning out pages of zeroes. Does this even make sense as an approach?

Comment: @Olly I suggest you write a new question with that (with a link to this one). Try to be as precise as possible about what you are trying to achieve.