# Matlab - use of principal components in finding longest axis of shape

Tags: image, matlab, find, pca, axes

I'm trying to use the `pca` function to find the longest axis of shapes in binary images. These are 2D images, so I'm expecting just two principal components. If I apply `pca` to the image itself I get many components.

My thoughts on this are that the matrix that `pca` acts on is treated such that rows are observations and columns are variables, so I need to convert my image into a list of the x,y coordinates of non-zero pixels. What function does this? Trying with `find`, this is what I have so far:

```
 for k=1:cellnum %for each cell...
     [nucleus, nucnum] = bwlabel(B5.*(cell==k)); %label nuclei in cell (Thanks @CapeCode)
    if nucnum == 1
      % other methods
      [row, col] = find(nucleus);
      [coeff, ~, eigen] = pca([row, col]);
      disp (coeff);
    end
```

I get two pairs of coefficients for each nucleus, as follows:

```
    0.8327    0.5537
   -0.5537    0.8327

    0.9791    0.2036
   -0.2036    0.9791

    0.8546    0.5193
   -0.5193    0.8546
```

so... am I actually doing what I think I'm doing?

Thanks,

Olly

Edit: Link to my earlier question regarding identification of overlapping objects, and Cape Code's elegant single-line solution - [Matlab - Identifying objects in one image that overlap objects in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26913819/matlab-identifying-objects-in-one-image-that-overlap-objects-in-another/26914729)

Comment: I think you want to do the PCA on the covariance matrix of the pixel coordinates. See if [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23596/why-is-the-eigenvector-of-a-covariance-matrix-equal-to-a-principal-component) thread doesn't help.

Comment: Not sure I understand. The find function gives me n observations of two variables (a list of x and y positions of pixels). If I do cov on that, I end up with just two numbers...

Comment: The covariance matrix will be 2x2. The eigenvectors of that matrix will give you the principal axes. The one associated with the largest eigenvector will the the one you want.

Comment: aha, so i should just use the `eig` function on the results of `find`?

Comment: Interesting - using `cov` and `eig` gives the same results as using `pca`, but in reverse order...

Comment: After reading `help pca`, it looks like you're right that it just does `cov` followed by `eig`. As for order, there's no real *order* of eigenvectors. Rather, each eigenvector is associated with an eigenvalue. By convention, one usually orders the eigenvalues in descending order, but there is no steadfast rule. I believe what you want is the eigenvector associated with the largest eigenvalue. According to `help pca`: "The columns are in descending order in terms of component variance," which means the first column is the one associated with the largest eigenvector. I hope that helps.